# PHP strtotime('2017W530') and strtotime('2018W010') both return same value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I save records to a MySQL database using `YEARWEEK(date, 0)`, and when I try to reverse it - using `strtotime(XXXXWXX0)` - I get the same value for year 2017, week 53 and year 2018, week 01:

Save to database:

```
YEARWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(1515232114), 0) => 201753
YEARWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(1515304499), 0) => 201801
```

Read from database:

```
strtotime('2017W530') => 151678400
strtotime('2018W010') => 151678400
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 2017 did not have 53 weeks, the last week was 52. started on December 25, 2017  ended on December 31, 2017

Comment: Month 13 would probably do the same thing.  YEARWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME()) is rounding / truncating so it's plausible that 52.5 and 53.4 both round to 53.